# how to add dots automatically while writing in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have one `TextBox` with binding on `DateTime` type. I need to get a dot after first 2 chars and second 2 chars, for example: 12.12.1990.
I'm using behavior in `TextChanged` event, that code:

```
void tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = tb.SelectionStart;
    if (i == 2 || i == 5)
    {                
        tb.Text += ".";
        tb.SelectionStart = i + 1;
    }
}
```

That is working, but if I want to delete text by backspace, obviously I can't delete dots, because event is called again.

What is better way to solve it?

### Solved

It works
But if you can, you may fix my algorithm.

```
        public string oldText = "";
        public string currText = "";
        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            oldText = currText;
            currText = TextBox1.Text;
            if (oldText.Length > currText.Length)
            {
                oldText = currText;
                return;
            }
            if (TextBox1.Text.Length == currText.Length)
            {
                if (TextBox1.SelectionStart == 2 || TextBox1.SelectionStart == 5)
                {
                    TextBox1.Text += ".";
                    TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Use [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @CuriousPen it's nothing that MaskedTextBox is WinForms Control? I'm junior and dont know any metnods/ways to do the "rightstyle".

Comment: @MC I'm using it. Textbox is part of datetimepicker. BUT, users wants that dots will show up in text automatic with theirs input

Comment: Use Date TimeControls for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the KeyPress event, so you can filter by what kind of key it was (using the KeyChar argument with Char.IsLetter() and similar functions).

Also, add the dot when the *next* key is pressed. If the user has typed "12", don't add a dot yet. When the user presses 1 to add the second "12", add it then (before the new character).

Comment: I should dont use TextChanged event?
I feel that I understand what you about, but not completely understant how to do it in code

Comment: My suggestion was to use a different event, yes, not TextChanged. However I think other suggestions may be better than mine, as mine would require a lot of conditions to catch.

Answer (score 1):

Use String Format in the xaml control like so

```
StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'
```

I just tested it and this will even convert slashes to the dots.

For example

```
<TextBox.Text>
 <Binding Path="Person.DateOfBirth" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'></Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

If you are using a datepicker then you will need to override its textbox template as in the link below with the String Format above.

[This link may help if if you are trying to apply it to a datepicker.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e55103a5-21df-4c59-b7b3-7e388ef024c9/wpf-datepicker-selecteddate-binding-format?forum=wpf)

Comment: It doesnt works, or maybe I doing it wrong?
Why not formatting after i tabbed on next element?

Comment: Have a look at the link added in my updated answer you may need to do that if you are using a datepicker control.

Comment: it just makes string formatted after I picked date and validation in textbox if I input something like "111111111", but I wants automatically adding and deleting dots in textbox. I wrote validation attributes to provide right date) but thanks for answer anyway, it so useful method

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a `DateTimePicker` and change its Format property to Short. Another option is to change your `TextBox` to a `MaskedTextBox` and changing its Mask property to `ShortDate (00/00/0000)` .`DateTimePicker` allows you not to do much about validating datetime values. But if you use a `MaskedTextBox` you should validate it. Sample [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208029/masked-textbox-validating-text-error) shows how to do validation.

Comment: Unfortunately, Im using it in silverlight too. No WinForms ref-s in project

Answer (score 0):

I have modified above code

```
        private void txt_in1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       int i = txt_in1.SelectionStart;
       if (bsp1 != 1)
       {
           if (i == 2)
           {
               txt_in1.Text += ":";
               txt_in1.SelectionStart = i + 1;
           }
       }

    }

    private void txt_in1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            bsp1 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            bsp1 = 0;
        }
    }
```

I have taken another event which is keyup (equivalent keypress event), In that whenever backspace is detected it will flag bsp1 variable, which intern stop the text change event to put ":". here "bsp1" is define as global variable. (Code is for wpf, c#).