# set own string format using c#

Tags: c#, string

I'm currently developing an application for our companys stock. In this application I have to create a format check button. So if the text in the textbox is not in the right format, it should throw an error.

I thought using `String.Format()` method but I think I'm doing it wrong and I don't know if it's possible using this method. I tried the following:

```
string format = String.Format("XXX.XX.XX.XX.X", txtStockFormat.Text);

if (format != txtStockFormat.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show("if");
}

else
{
    MessageBox.Show("else");
}
```

I don't know if `String.Format()` is the right way to achieve what I want and I think I don't quite understand it right. I already searched on [this site](https://pdmlab.com/samples/stringformatting/) and I saw that there are loads of given formats but I couldn't found a way to set my own format.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this?

Suggestion appreciated :)

Comment: `string Format`, formats strings. It doesn't validate the format.Maybe you are looking for regular expressions ?

Comment: sounds like you are looking for a regex pattern

Comment: Oh, nice to know. I'll search for that, thanks :)

Comment: try with regular expressions

Comment: use regex match - http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208029/masked-textbox-validating-text-error, maybe it is another valid approach for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments on your question already said, you have to use `Regex`. I had a similar problem about 1 month ago and it took me a while to understand how `Regex` works.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]";
Match match = Regex.Match(txtStockFormat.Text, pattern);

if (match.Success)
{
    // Do your stuff
}

else
{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

In your question you wanted the format `XXX.XX.XX.XX.X`. So let's have a look at the first three letters. In my code example the first three letters could be "a-z", "A-Z" and numbers from "0-9". If you want only uppercase letters for the first three chars you have to change the pattern to `[A-Z]`.

```
string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]";
                        ^           ^         ^      ^
                        |           |         |      |
                    1st char   2nd char   3rd char  Point (separator)      etc.
```

You can just replace the pattern I wrote above with the pattern you want. I defined the pattern for your example you posted in your question.

**UPDATE:**

As @Rawling already said in the comments, to make it clearer and simpler, this will have the same effect:

```
string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I now understand a bit of `Regex` and how to use it. Thanks man! =)

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]` can be `[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}` if you're feeling less verbose.

Comment: @Rawling Ah thanks, didn't know that :) That make it much simpler and clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, as you asked to set a string format but in code you are trying to compare a text with that format.
Anyway if you want to change a string to your own desired format, you can simply use ToString method like _yourString.ToString(_yourFormat).